# How do I access a Magento 2 website codebase / directory files?

Tags: php, frontend, magento2, codebase

As you can probably tell, I am new to Magento2 and I am trying to figure out some of the basics. I'm a full-stack developer that is use to developing (frontend and backend) myself then using docker and finally hosting it on an AWS:S3/EC2 or AWS: Elastic Beanstalk. With that said, Magento seems like a completely different beast to conquer.

I have a family member who is wanting me to do some basic frontend stuff for their website (such as changing Navbar design and a potential home page overhaul later on), naturally wanting to help them out I agreed to have a look and see what I can do. I have access to their Magento 2 dashboard area and have been looking around with no sure luck thus far. I have researched online that Magento 2 allows for a "Page Builder" or a "WYSIWYG" type functionality. But I am unable to use these types of tools because my family member had the website built by a Magento 2 developer firm awhile back and everything is coded manually and could cause problems if using one of the above mentioned tools. Due to this I am trying to get access to their site directory so that I can go in and make the necessary changes and upload the files. But I am really struggling on how to access the codebase.

I have read that an admin needs to send me the code??? Or grant me access to the code or something along those lines? I do have the host, port, root, username, password, etc. for the live server but still having trouble.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your exact question about this? How to use Magento as a end-user? How to perform any specific programming operation?

Comment: Usually, you should check which files need to be changed to adjust whatever you want to adjust. As this is not standardized, there is no explicit hint about how to find such files

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ssh to access the server

```
ssh user@host -p port
```

After you get into the server, you should set up a git repository in the project root and push the code from the server to the repository, then clone the repo to your local environment.

From there on, it's the normal development flow. You can use a clean database with sample data or you can dump the db from the live env and use it on your local env, but this will require some changes in the db after the import.

Detailing all the steps required to do this task would take forever and would cover a lot of different issues/steps.

"I have read that an admin needs to send me the code???"
Not sure what you mean by this, but a Magento admin is just a user on the backend side of the website. He does not have access to any code.
A git repository admin(probably previous dev) could grant you access to the code repository, but this doesn't seem like an option.